# Chrome devtools show h2 instead of quic/h3 (even if the page is using HTTP/3.0)

Tags: google-chrome, http, tcp, google-chrome-devtools, quic

As a developer I am very excited about the next version of HTTP/3.0. I noticed some time ago that when I opened Google.com then I could see in Devtools > Network that the protocol appeared as Quic. But now when I open it I only see h2 instead. Why is that?

I also noticed that the alt-svc header indicates that the resource is also available over quick. But it's still loading over h2.

```
alt-svc: quic=":443";
```

[image]

I noticed the same thing using curl, that the protocol used is h2 not h3. But Google has been using Quic for years now. Why this change?

```
curl -v https://www.google.com/

* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)

> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: The stable channel is too "old" so the new quic isn't working there I guess. Canary shows `http/2+quic/46`. For more details use `chrome://net-export/` to inspect the internals of the requests.

Comment: @wOxxOm hmm.. for some reason it still shows h2 even in Canary

Comment: Try changing `chrome://flags/#enable-quic`

Comment: @wOxxOm I changed "Experimental QUIC protocol" from Default to Enabled, restarted browser but still showing h2. (tried both stable and canary)

Comment: Inspect the internals then in `chrome://net-export/`

Comment: UPDATE: I was using Windows 7 and then I tried to do it on Windows 10 and it is showing "http/2+quic/46". I don't understand why it wasn't showing it on Windows 7. Maybe they have a different build for Win 7.